# Datagrid View Dropdown list Event handler

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

I have added a dropdown column in DGridview but i am unable to generate event that should fire when any value from dropdown menu is selected.
Here is the code for adding column

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn com = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();

            com.HeaderText = "";
            com.Items.Add( "Print Invoice");
            com.Items.Add("Print Job Card");            
            com.Items.Add("Close Job Card");            
            createCol = false;            
            ViewActiveJobs.Columns.Add(com);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.You have to create new Event handler for Combobox and call that event in

EditingControlShowing .

```
 private void ViewActiveJobs_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)

    {

    comboBOX = (ComboBox)e.Control;

    comboBOX .SelectedIndexChanged -=new EventHandler(comboBOX _SelectedIndexChanged);
    comboBOX .SelectedIndexChanged +=new EventHandler(comboBOX _SelectedIndexChanged);

    }


    private void comboBOX _SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {

    ComboBox combo = sender as ComboBox;
    string str=combo.SelectedIndex.ToString();

    }
```

Comment: Helps alot but there is one problem that messagebox ok appears 5 or 4 times when i click combobox

Comment: @ Afnan:I simply added messageBox in `SelectedIndexChanged` .U can access it has ComboBox and do whatever you want.